# Visualizing street shape data for London?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I am trying to visualise some street-level data I got, but since I'm very new to GIS I don't know the correct terminology to Google. My data looks like this:

```
Street, Incident Count
Congo Road, 12
Roydene Rd, 21
....
```

Using a combination of geocoding and Leaflet.js, I managed to get something like this:

[image: current state]

However, with geocoding I only get the geometric center of each street, so the visualisation isn't very informative. I'd like to get an image, where each street is colour-coded according to how many incidents occurred in it, e.g (excuse my poor Paint skills)

[image: Desired effect]

I was thinking I can use OSM to get the coordinates of each node that a street consists of, so I'd be able to represent a street as a collection of points, which would make the visualisation a bit better.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: OS Open Roads (Open Data from Ordnance Survey) https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html the data is good for attaching your own attributes

Comment: Thematic Mapping (TFL have roads level thematic map) http://content.tfl.gov.uk/traffic-note-1-traffic-levels-in-greater-london-2010.pdf

Comment: You could get the street lines from OSM or the ordnance survey, break them up into short sections (optional), attach the incidence data to the street lines by a **table join** based on the street name attribute -or- a **spatial join** -or- **intersection**, calculate points-per-distance for each street as `[the number of points on each line segment] / [the length of that line segment]`, and color-code the lines based on their points-per-distance value. I don't know the exact steps in Leaflet, but it should be a fairly simple task in any GIS. The bold terms should help with Googling.